# Selecting rows from a data frame based on previous values - a provided solution not working

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I'm trying to do exactly what the user in this thread was trying to do:

[Select specific rows based on previous row value (in the same column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843826/select-specific-rows-based-on-previous-row-value-in-the-same-column)

The basic idea is to select all the rows with the value 20 in the column Type that immediately follow a row with a value 40 in the column Type. The final result should be a dataframe with only the rows with values 20 or 40 in the column Type.

The solution provided looks like this:

```
# Get indices of rows that meet condition
ind2 <- which(df$Type==20 & dplyr::lag(df$Type)==40)
# Get indices of rows before the ones that meet condition
ind1 <- which(df$Type==20 & dplyr::lag(df$Type)==40)-1
```

This works and I can see that the right rows have been selected.

But the final step of subsetting the data

```
df[c(ind1,ind2)]
```

returns an error message:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, c(ind1, ind2)) : undefined columns selected
```

I can't figure out why this is happening. Any ideas to get past this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: `df[c(ind1,ind2),]` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

As correctly Abdou stated: `df[c(ind1,ind2)]` is incomplete.
Whenever you use a matrix or a data frame then the square brackets indicate this: `[ rows , columns ]`.

In your case you indicated for the dataframe to select a combination of `ind1 and ind2`, without telling it to look either in the rows or columns. As a result the error you got. Speciffically R will consider looking through the columns based on those `ind1` and `ind2` specifications.

Simply clarifying it as `df[c(ind1,ind2),]` your `df` will show all the rows that contain the values you want.

Comment: Your explanation isn't really correct. Indexing a data.frame with only one vector eg `df[c(ind1, ind2)]` will be treated as indexing on columns only, which is valid code and works as long as those columns exist. (In contrast, data.tables would treat this as indexing on rows only, which may be the mistake made in the example)

Comment: That is correct, I was just indicating it since he only wanted to get the rows. That's why i said it is incomplete. Also since columns named as `ind1` and `ind2` don't exist in his data.

Comment: Yes, so your middle section is incorrect/misleading and would be better removed to avoid confusion. The code tells to look in columns (not neither as you suggest), and R is not looking in rows first as you suggest - it's not looking in rows at all.