# How to filter rows based on the previous row and keep previous row using dplyr?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, conditional-statements, subset

I am trying to subset rows of a data set using a condition that's based on the previous row, whilst keeping the previous row in the subsetted data. This is essentially the same as the question here, but I am looking for a dplyr approach:

[Select specific rows based on previous row value (in the same column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843826/select-specific-rows-based-on-previous-row-value-in-the-same-column)

I have taken the dplyr approach applied in the comments to that answer, but I am unable to figure out the last step of retaining the previous row.

I can get the rows that support the condition I'm interested in (`incorrect` when the previous row is not `enter`).

```
set.seed(123)
x=c("enter","incorrect","enter","correct","incorrect",
"enter","correct","enter","incorrect")
y=c(runif(9, 5.0, 7.5))
z=data.frame(x,y)

filter(z, x=="incorrect" & lag(x)!="enter")
```

Which gives, as expected:

```
      x        y
1 incorrect 7.351168
```

What I would like to produce is this, so that all rows I've filtered based on the condition are stored with the row that precedes them in the original data set:

```
        x        y
1   correct 7.207544
2 incorrect 7.351168
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you show the expected output

Comment: It would be helpful to show the expected output.  Perhaps `z %>% slice(which(x == "incorrect" & lag(x) != "enter") + c(-1, 0))`

Comment: *"Which sort of works, but it returns rows containing enter that precede cases other than incorrect."* I don't see this. If you add `z$id = 1:nrow(z)` you'll see that ids 1 and 8 are "enter" and precede "incorrect", and exactly those "enter" rows are kept by `filter(z,x=="incorrect" & lag(x)!="enter" | x=="enter" & 
lead(x)=="incorrect")`. If that's not what you want, please explain why and show the output you do want.

Comment: @Gregor apologies, my attempt to solve the issue was misleading, so I've updated and added an expected output. Hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By filtering you could do:

```
z %>%
  filter( (x == "incorrect" & lag(x) != "enter") | lead(x == "incorrect" & lag(x) != "enter") )
```

Giving:

```
          x        y
1   correct 7.207544
2 incorrect 7.351168
```

Comment: Just so I fully understand, why is the first condition `(x == "incorrect" & lag(x) != "enter")` enclosed in brackets, but the second `lead(x == "incorrect" & lag(x) != "enter")` is not? Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: The second condition is enclosed in brackets the same way the first one is; the `lead` part doesn't bring any new condition to be evaluated, it just looks for the next  row in which the condition in brackets is `TRUE`.