# remove rows dynamically in r

Tags: r, for-loop

I need to remove rows dynamically from a dataframe based on a date criteria.

if the start date is greater than the last start date read, and the ending date is lesser than the last ending date read, I want to remove the row from the dataset.

can someone come up with a solution? it doesn't need to be with a for loop.

```
for (i in 2:nrow(df)) {
  if ((df$start_date[i] > df$start_date[i-1]) & (df$end_date[i] < df$end_date[i-1])){
    REMOVE ROW [i] from dataframe
  }
}
```

Comment: check out the `lag()` function in the `dplyr` pckage. that will look at the previous element and will be able to do what you want. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54348952/how-to-filter-rows-based-on-the-previous-row-and-keep-previous-row-using-dplyr

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @morgan121 you can use `lag` get value from previous row. You can use it in `filter` however, `filter` keeps the row which satisfy the condition, so you can try :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(!(start_date > lag(start_date, default = first(start_date)) & 
         end_date < lag(end_date, default = first(end_date))))
```

Comment: You could also just reverse the conditions (`start_date < lag(start_date), end_date > lag(end_date)`) to retain the desired rows using `filter`.