# dplyr::filter rows with characters using lag/lead matching several columns

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, tidyverse, lag

I am attempting to filter rows from a dataframe (`df`) using the contents in specific columns (`col1`, `col2`, and `col3`) in the next row.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54348952/how-to-filter-rows-based-on-the-previous-row-and-keep-previous-row-using-dplyr) got close but only uses one column to lag

Most of the posts showing how to filter using lag/lead have columns which are numbers, in my case they are all text.

```r
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~col1,  ~col2,     ~col3,          ~Effect,
  "Jim", "Walk", "optionA",      "col1×col2",
  "Jim", "Walk", "optionA", "col1×col2×col2",
  "Jim",  "Run", "optionB",           "col1",
  "Jim",  "Run", "optionB",      "col1×col2",
  "Jim",  "Run", "optionB", "col1×col2×col2",
  "Joe", "Walk", "optionA",           "col1",
  "Joe", "Walk", "optionA",      "col1×col2",
  "Joe",  "Run", "optionB", "col1×col2×col2"
  )
```

I would like to filter rows if the next row (except the `Effect` column) is identical.

The final dataframe would look like this

```r
df_result <- tibble::tribble(
  ~col1,  ~col2,     ~col3,          ~Effect,
  "Jim", "Walk", "optionA", "col1×col2×col2",
  "Jim",  "Run", "optionB", "col1×col2×col2",
  "Joe", "Walk", "optionA",      "col1×col2",
  "Joe",  "Run", "optionB", "col1×col2×col2"
  )
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? If possible I would like to use the tidyverse to get the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   slice(rev(row_number())) %>%
  distinct(across(col1:col3), .keep_all = TRUE)
```

-ouptut

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  col1  col2  col3    Effect        
  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>         
1 Joe   Run   optionB col1×col2×col2
2 Joe   Walk  optionA col1×col2     
3 Jim   Run   optionB col1×col2×col2
4 Jim   Walk  optionA col1×col2×col2
```

---

Or using `nchar`

```
df %>%
    group_by(across(col1:col3)) %>%
    slice(which.max(nchar(Effect))) %>% 
    ungroup
```

Answer (score 3):

A `tidyverse` solution could be

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(across(-Effect)) %>% 
  slice_tail(n = 1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  col1  col2  col3    Effect        
  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>         
1 Jim   Run   optionB col1×col2×col2
2 Jim   Walk  optionA col1×col2×col2
3 Joe   Run   optionB col1×col2×col2
4 Joe   Walk  optionA col1×col2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `duplicated` with option `fromLast = TRUE` like below

```
df[!duplicated(df[-4], fromLast = TRUE), ]
```